# What is the proper way to check multiple form values from the template in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

There are a bunch of valid search combinations, and I want to disable the form unless a valid search fields have been entered. Currently I have a method isValidSearchCombo() I'm calling from the template, but I understand that is not best practice because change detection doesnt know when it needs to be re-run.

What is the best way to watch these fields and toggle a disableSearchButton boolean?

```html
<button
  id="submit_button"
  type="submit"
  mat-flat-button
  [disabled]="!this.isValidSearchCombo()"
>
```

```js
isValidSearchCombo(): boolean {
  return Boolean(
    this.searchForm.value.firstName
    && this.searchForm.value.lastName
    && this.searchForm.value.state
    || (this.searchForm.value.foo && (this.searchForm.value.bar || this.searchForm.value.fooBar))
    || (this.searchForm.value.barFoo)
  );
}
```

Comment: what about `this.searchForm.valid` / `this.searchForm.invalid` ?

Comment: That will just check that all of the fields are valid, I need to know is certain combinations of fields have been filled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `searchForm` seems to be an Angular form, a change detection friendly version of that would be:

```js
isValidSearchCombo: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.searchForm.valueChange.subscribe((value) => {
    this.isValidSearchCombo = Boolean(
      value.firstName
      && value.lastName
      && value.state
      || (value.foo && (value.bar || value.fooBar))
      || (value.barFoo)
    );
  });
}
```

```html
<button
  id="submit_button"
  type="submit"
  mat-flat-button
  [disabled]="!isValidSearchCombo">
```